# How can I detect normal Bluetooth connection In HMS Awareness?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

In Bluetooth Awareness **device type value 0** indicates car stereo. Is it possible to indicate normal Bluetooth by using any other device type value. I used 1 and other values but it is not detecting.

Answer (score 0):

Currenltly Bluetooth awarenss can only identify Car Stero.
To know more about Bluetooth awareness you can use the link
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-References/awareness-barrier-bluetoothbarrier